# Let's Encrypt with dynamic subdomains

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

Setup is like this. I've got a domain e.g. `example.com`
I've setup Apache2 with a `VirtualDocumentRoot`, this way I can point a subdomain to a specific folder in an easy way:

**File `sites-available/websites.conf`:**

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/websites/%1/

<Directory /var/www/websites/%1/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So when you visit `test.example.com` it searches for `test` folder under websites directory and serves it.

This works as intended, but I wanted to use Let's Encrypt for SSL. Which cannot yet handle wildcard certificates. How would I tackle such a problem?

**Current situation:**

Installed let's encrypt certs with: `sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d admin.example.com -d www.example.com`

**File: `sites-available/000-default.conf`:**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/websites/current/

<Directory /var/www/websites/current/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>

# Let's Encrypt Redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

All subdomains still get redirected to `https`. Only topdomain `example.com`, `admin.example.com` and `www.example.com` should be https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not scoped any of the configuration in any site-specific way.

It's important to note that the separate config files "per site" is not really an Apache httpd feature. It's just a (relatively common) convention for administrative convenience which in the end uses an `Include` directive in the main configuration file to merge everything together into a single configuration when the configuration is loaded.

Normally these separate configuration files have all their contents inside `VirtualHost` to scope their effects, but you seem to have only global configuration, including your http to https redirects.

Comment: Okay, so how should I implement Let's Encrypt on those subdomains? Should I really separate every subdomain in its own .conf file? Then dynamic hosting would not work anymore. And then I need to do a lot of work when I want to create a new subdomain

Comment: You can have one virtualhost (in one file) for `*.example.com` and one for `example.com`, `admin.example.com` and `www.example.com` (or have these separated if they are actually different sites?). The point is that you need to separate the configuration for `*.example.com` from the vhost(s) where you do https.

Comment: @MDijkstra Point being, it looks like you intended to separate things this way based on how you split it into different files, only you then put everything in the global scope.

Answer (score -2):

Trying to create certificates from server

```
certbot certonly -d *.example.com -d admin.example.com -d www.example.com
Wildcard domains are not supported: *.example.com
```

Comment: I hate from this site, many people down vote without explain why, letsencrypt doesn't support wildcard

Comment: This "answer" only repeats something that was already stated in the question, though.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Why are you suggesting this? As far as I know, let's encrypt does not support wildcards...

Comment: @MDijkstra you need to have multie certificates and multiple virtualhosts, if you cannot use wildcards